# How can I drag a list or button element from its parent div to another div using jsplumb

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I have a div element which consists of list elements eg: java, ror, .NET.

I want to drag a particular list suppose only java from its current div element to another div element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com). Particularly into the [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/). The [shopping cart](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#shopping-cart) example described there, it's probably something you are looking for.

Comment: you are welcome. And don't forget to accept later this answer, if it solved your problem.

Comment: sorry. i didn't familiar with that thing